# Can't install eucalyptus

Tags: linux, cloud, eucalyptus

I have a VM with storage size as 20 GB. I begin setup eucalyptus by Eucalyptus FastStart, i use to command:

```
bash <(curl -Ls eucalyptus.com/install)
```

But It appear mistake,and this is log file of eucalyptus:

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf unfair_spinlock pni vmx ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb dts tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf unfair_spinlock pni vmx ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb dts tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security, versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * elrepo: mirrors.thzhost.com
 * epel: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * extras: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * updates: mirrors.vinahost.vn
Package git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
.....
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] INFO: yum_package[eucalyptus-sc] sending create action to template[eucalyptus.conf] (delayed)
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] INFO: Processing template[eucalyptus.conf] action create (eucalyptus::storage-controller line 46)
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-05T14:02:10+07:00] ERROR: execute[Wait for resource availability] (eucalyptus::create-first-resources line 48) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of source /root/eucarc && euca-describe-availability-zones verbose | grep m1.small | grep -v 0000 ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of source /root/eucarc && euca-describe-availability-zones verbose | grep m1.small | grep -v 0000 ----
Ran source /root/eucarc && euca-describe-availability-zones verbose | grep m1.small | grep -v 0000 returned 1
[2014-12-05T14:02:13+07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I don't understand what it's to talk to me. Any help?

Cheers,

Nghiep.

Comment: Sorry, this place is for _programming_ related questions. Please ask your question over at the SuperUser site. You see the link at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it , It mistake because i provice not enough storage size for eucalyptus. Eucalyptus recommend manimum 100Gb